# How do you generate a shuffled sequence with ScalaCheck?

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I've been trying to generate shuffled sequences with scalacheck. Scalacheck doesn't provide any generator to do it straightforwardly, and I couldn't find any easy answer online. After a bit of thinking, below is how I did it. I hope others will find if useful.

Comment: SO is not a place to showcase answers. Create a gist in GitHub or something similar.

Comment: @I.K. there: https://gist.github.com/guillaumecherel/4f0532a61db73f768242

Comment: Self-answered questions [are fine](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)—this just isn't a very good example of one. The question should be stated fully, and the answer should be more than a big chunk of awkwardly formatted code.

Comment: @TravisBrown I edited the question to state it clearly as you suggested. As for the code, I don't see how the formatting is awkward. In all cases, I wrote this question and answer because I had been looking for it and couldn't find it. Anyone also looking for it in the future may be glad to find it in the future. This is a succint but correct answer to a valid question, and as such is valuable. The downvotes seem excessive to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.scalacheck.Gen.pick(n: Int, l: Iterable[T]): Gen[Seq[T]]` picks `n` distinct elements from `l` in random order. Call `pick` with `n = l.length`, and you will generate a randomly

Comment: This doesn't work. I wanted a list with the integers between 1 and n (also random) in a random order, I wrote the following generator, but it generates only numbers in ascending order: Gen.choose(0, 10).flatMap(len => Gen.pick(len, 1 to len))

Comment: It doesn't select in random order at the moment see this [issue](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/issues/355)

Comment: You're right. I think the best solution would be to copy to an Array and apply the standard random permutation algorithm over arrays using swapping by generating the vector [rand(length), rand(length - 1), rand(length - 2), ...] of random swap indices with scalacheck and using those indices to swap successive elements of the array. Then convert back to a Seq. I haven't looked at Scala in a while. Would you like to propose this as a solution?

Comment: By the way, this is known as a Knuth or Fisher-Yates Shuffle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Answer (score 3):

You could use a collection shuffling algorithm (such as the one in scala.util.Random) to obtain a clearer solution:

```
/**
 * This represents a potential list shuffling. It
 * acts as a pure function - when applied to the
 * same list it always returns the same result
 */
class Shuffling(seed: Int) {
  def apply[T](xs: Seq[T]): Seq[T] = {
    val r = new scala.util.Random(seed)
    r.shuffle(xs)
  }
}

import org.scalacheck.Arbitrary._
import org.scalacheck.Gen

val shufflingGen: Gen[Shuffling] = arbitrary[Int].map(new Shuffling(_))
```

The above snippet defines a `shuffling` - a possible re-ordering of a list. It also defines a generator that provides arbitrary shuffling instances. The following example shows how you would use a shuffling to re-order a range of integers:

```
def shuffledRange(n: Int): Gen[Seq[Int]] = {
  for {
    shuffling <- shufflingGen
  } yield shuffling(Range(0, n))
}
```

It may seem odd to add one level of indirection in the form of the `Shuffling` class - we could just as well apply `Random.shuffle` directly on the list. This is because we want to avoid an additional source of randomness in addition to the implicit randomizing Scalacheck is already doing in the background - the source of randomness in the shuffling comes from a scalacheck generator.

One benefit to this would be the reproducibility of generated cases (whenever Scalacheck [will support it](https://github.com/rickynils/scalacheck/issues/67)).

Answer (score 0):

```
def shuffle[T](s: Seq[T], prefix: Seq[T] = Vector()): Gen[Seq[T]] =
    if (s.length == 0) Gen.const(prefix.toSeq)
    else
      Gen.choose(0, s.length - 1)
        .flatMap { i => 
          shuffle(
            s.take(i) ++ s.takeRight(s.length - i - 1), 
            prefix :+ s(i)) }
```